# Trouble with Igraph library

Tags: python-3.x, igraph

I'm  trying to use `igraph` in `python 3` :

```
g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
```

the anwser should be

```
 g.vs["name"]
 ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
```

but the answer I've got is :

```
g.vs["name"]
[]
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Despite appearances, `igraph.Graph.vs` is not a dictionary (where your assignment would be expected to work) but of type `igraph.VertexSeq`. Unlike a dictionary, `igraph.Graph.vs[some_attribute]` only allows you to *get* the data, not to *set* the data. To add nodes with the indicated names. do the following:

```
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertices(["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"])
print g.vs['name']
# ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
```

Comment: I only have python 2.7 on my machine, but I would be surprised if it doesn't work in python 3. Have you tried it?